# Как в WSL Ubuntu поменять pip path на Директрорию из win11/win10?

Tags: python, ubuntu, bash, pip, wsl

В общем, столкнулся я с такой проблемой, что я прописываю в /.config/pip/pip.conf `[global] target= и тут директория где у меня хранятся все библиотеки из python //root/mnt/c/.../Python38-32/site-packages` В итоге ubuntu говорит, мол, друг, эта папка уже существует. Но при этом не читает лежащие внутри нее зависимости. Знает кто, что делать?
Вкратце: Мне нужно чтобы pip внутри wsl ubuntu видел все библиотеки из windows pip'а, и, естественно использовал их.

UPD: В общем, когда мы пишем с вами `pip -V` - он выдает `from .../pip`. Как бы мне заменить это `from` с `/usr/local/.../pip` на `//root/mnt/c/.../pip`

Answer (score 0):

Python38-32 и Python из WSL не совместимы. Один в формате PE 32 бит, второй ELF 64 бит.

> заменить это from с /usr/local/.../pip на //root/mnt/c/.../pip

Например подстановка папки через ссылку может сломать систему WSL

```
ln -sf //root/mnt/c/.../pip /usr/local/.../pip
```